# gmap3 get cluster Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

Heyo, i´m using gmap3 and i want to click on a cluster and set the map´s center to that position with zoom.

like
?

```
cluster:{
    radius: 20,
    events:{ // events trigged by clusters
      click:function(cluster){
            var map = $(this).gmap3("get");
            map.panTo($(cluster).getPosition());
            map.setZoom(18);
            destin = $(cluster).getPosition();;
}
```

but it causes

---

> TypeError: $(...).getPosition is not a function

---

any help?  can´t figure out tryed alot, hope it´s not impossible, the gmap3 forum seems a bit spammed too

thanks in advance for any hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
cluster.main.getPosition()
```

instead of

```
 $(cluster).getPosition()
```